# Why does not rendering to html page work in POST action on the server?

Tags: node.js, express, post, backend

Every time that i do a post action it reaches the server and the code works. The problem is when at the end i want to render to a new html page. The code should work (the rendering works for get actions) and no error or warning is thrown.

```
server.get("/home", function(req, res) {
 renderPage(res, "home");
});

function renderPage(res, pageName) {
 res.sendFile(__dirname +  '/public/views/' + pageName + '.html');
}

...

server.post("/registration", function(req, res){
 ...
 res.redirect("home");
 ...
}
```

I expect that the the application redirects to the home html file when called.

Comment: I am using nodejs and expressjs.

Answer (score 0):

You need the preceding slash on your route in the `redirect` call:

```
res.redirect("/home");
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I get to renderPage function and no errors are thrown, but still the client does not load the new page...

Comment: @MatejKalc can you add a callback as the second argument to `res. sendFile`, one like: `err => console.log(err)`?

Comment: I did it and like it prints null.